# Create nested table using presto?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, presto, amazon-athena

If I have a spark schema of this structure,

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- orders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- userid: long (nullable = true)
```

How to create a table with this schema,
I tried with this query,

```
CREATE TABLE iceberg.test.order (
id BIGINT,
firstName VARCHAR,
lastName VARCHAR,
orders ROW(
    id BIGINT,
    price double,
    userid BIGINT
        )
                )
WITH (
  format = 'PARQUET'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a table. to read existing parquet files on s3, the syntaxt looks like the example below. I adapted it to the schema you are displaying: orders is an array of struct.

```
create external table mytable (
   id bigint,
   firstname varchar, 
   lastname varchar, 
   orders array[struct<id:bigint, price:double, userid:bigint>]
) stored as parquet
location 's3://...'
```

here are more examples: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/

Comment: The syntax is `array<struct<…>>` (i.e. no square brackets).